# Why is my question downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvoting

My question [Why is OpenJDK not preinstalled](https://askubuntu.com/q/311089/134848) was downvoted 2 times.

What's wrong with it?

Or is it just that people think preinstalling it is a stupid idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I've given you an answer.

Most "why isn't this the case" questions are probably viewed as being argumentative or a feature request, neither of which are thread types we really support here. We're primarily here to solve problems and those sorts of questions sometimes just don't have atomic answers.

Answer (score 1):

> What's wrong with it?

Because it cannot be answered objectively. Oli is guessing that is an space issue. Well, the iso had ~80 MiB free about 6-7 years ago and didn't include it either. That's not the answer either. We can play the guessing game all day long and will not even know whenever the answer is correct or not. Those kind of questions, which require a non-trivial amount of guesswork, are closed as "opinion based" and I've voted to close it.